# how to model two fields as one

Tags: uml

I have a project where one of the requirements is that username has same value as email. How should I model this on my UML diagram ? Should class User have two fields: username, email. Or maybe I can create one field email and make some kind of markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create both fields and write an OCL constraint stating that both must have the same value. The constraint could be as simple as context User inv:  self.username=self.email

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for the anser

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
-email : string
```

---

```
+getUserName()
+setUserName(string)
+getEmail()
+setEmail(string)
```

Comment: i`m not asking about implementation. I`m wondering how to show it on UML diagram in the analysis stage (still thank you for the response)